# What is the minimum Premium to be asked for a risk X?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, finance, risk-assessment

Suppose that an insurer has an exponential utility function $u(x) =-2e^{-2x}.$ What is the minimum premium $P^{-}$ to be asked for a risk X?

[image]

I got some hint for this, but I could not understand this hint.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but isn't the minimum premium the expectation of the utility function?

Comment: Isn't it strange that the hint is given before the question is stated?

Comment: @Kiran Was my answer useful? It wasn't really clear to me what was it that you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can get you started:

What I understood from the picture is that the person who wants to be insured has an exponential utility function with parameter one $$u(x)=-e^{-x},$$ and that the risk $X$ is random with distribution $\text{Exp}(2)$, that is, the expected value of a function $f$ of $X$ is $$\mathbb E(f(X))=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,2e^{-2x}\, dx.$$

Suppose that the person's initial wealth is $W$. He has two options: either take the risk $X$, which I interpret means to lose a random amount of money equal to $X$, or to pay a premium $P^-$ which will keep him safe from the risk.

If he takes the first option his wealth in the future will be random and equal to $W-X,$ whereas if he takes the other one his wealth will be surely $W-P^-.$

In order for the premium to be a fair price to pay the insured wants to expect at least the same utility loss from these two options, which means that the condition for the maximum premium is $$u(W-P^-)=\mathbb E[u(W-X)]. $$ It only remains to compute.

Comment: this problem is similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524383/probability-density-and-expected-value Would you be able to help me with it? Thank you.